# Displaying user's password

Tags: oracle, password-recovery

I need to know if there is a way in SQL*Plus to display the password of a certain username?

At my job, sometimes the developers ask me what happened to their account, and what their password is. When I try to display the username and password, the password shows as blank.

Could you please help?

Answer (score 13):

What you are asking is impossible, unless you brute-force the password hash for the user.

How do you expect a system to be secure if passwords are stored in plain text?

Answer (score -3):

You can user this:

```
SELECT name,
       ctime,           -- create time
       ptime            -- change 
FROM   sys.user$
WHERE  name = '<USER NAME>';
```

Of course there is no (easy) way to decrypt Oracle passwords.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: This is real life situation. You can tell developers at least WHEN then password was changed. Then with some effort you can guess by whom it was changed. Of course you can not tell what the new password is. But at least you can identify the "culprit".

Comment: Judging by the fact that the OP is able to display the username and blank password field, it seems they already know how to query this information.

Comment: In addition, I would rather query `dba_users` which includes `account_status`, `lock_date` and `expiry_date`.

Answer (score -3):

Phil's answer gets to the point: there shouldn't be **any** way at all for you to get users' passwords, that's really insecure because getting access to the DB would expose all system access.

Password recovery should always depend on the user alone via a password recovery e-mail or something like that, which probably isn't up to you but to the people in charge of the application.

Comment: "people in charge of the application"? We're talking about developers coming to the DBA. The DBA is in charge of this application (Oracle DBMS).

Comment: Yes, but it is very unlikely that a password recovery feature is gonna be implemented at DB level. I meant the people not working in the DB layer.

Comment: And my point is the question is *explicitly* about the DB layer! SQL*Plus, developers, DBA.

Comment: I don't see the misunderstanding here. I know what OP asked, and my answer to his/her question is that password recovery shouldn't be his/her concern, so unless more information about the implementation is given (maybe the passwords are in fact stored in plain text or decryption is possible) then the developers really need to implement a password recovery feature for themselves. Unless, of course, we want to answer with a really bad development practice.